# Не передается GameObject в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Создал объект, прикрепил к нему скрипт, в котором используется GameObject. при попытке прикрепить необходимый GameObject ничего не происходит. Пробовал и через префабы, но ничего не вышло(не работает Dragn‘Drop и прикрепление через выбор файла)

```
public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Font font;
  public GameObject obstacle;

  void Start()
  {
    float DTime = 0;
    float TimeS = 2;
    InvokeRepeating("AddObs", DTime, TimeS);
  }

  void AddObs()
  {
    Instantiate(obstacle);
  }

  private void Update()
  {
    if (BirdScript.GameOver)
      CancelInvoke();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Прикрепляйте, пожалуйста, код к вопросу, догадаться, в чем у вас там проблема, довольно трудно без кода.

Comment: Код должен работать. Что значит "ничего не вышло"? Dragn`Drop не работает?

Comment: Проверил у себя - код рабочий, да и ошибиться тут негде. Вы точно пытаетесь прикрепить игровой объект?

Comment: Да, font прикреплялся, а объект нет, как был None(GameObject), так и оставался

Comment: Погодите, вы пытаетесь прикрепить объект со сцены к скрипту префаба? Проясните ситуацию, что и куда вы прикрепляете, это важно.

Comment: Не, есть объект генератор, у него данный скрипт, я к нему хочу прикрепить префаб, который хочу генерировать